# Corner radius for view after setting text

Tags: swift, cornerradius

I have a `UIView` that contains a `UILabel`. The size of the `UIView` adapts to the size of the `UILabel`.

I want the `UIView` to be a circle so I set the corner radius:

```
view.clipToBounds = true
label.text = "123"
view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.size.height / 2
```

However, if I call the code above, the corner radius is not adapted sometimes. It seems as if the `UIView` frame did not change its size yet. The `UIView` is inside a `UITableViewCell` btw.

Comment: "not adapted **sometimes**"?

Comment: Yes, sometimes... quite strange... it is executed on a the main thread though.

Comment: I actually noticed that not only the corner radius varies but also the size of the view containing the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind subclassing you can do the following:

```
import UIKit

class RoundedView: UIView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.height / 2.0
    }

}
```

This will adjust the corner radius to the appropriate height anytime the view is resized.

Comment: It worked, but then the size of the rounded view kept varying. I found out that the problem was actually the NSLayoutConstraints in the storyboard. The rounded view had a layout constraint on the right side and a "greater than or equal" to another UILabel on the left side. The constraint was preventing the rounded view from resizing according to it's label subview. Removing the left constraint solved the problem.